# URL stays same when returning different view of same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to return a different view from my controller. However, although the correct view is displayed the URL stays same.

This is my form in `/Company/Create` view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Company", FormMethod.Post)) 
{ 
 // Form here
}
```

So basically, the form and model is submitted to `/Company/Create` action. If the submitted model is valid, then I process the data and redirect to /Company/Index view with

```
return View("Index");
```

As I said, correct view is displayed however, URL (address bar) is still `http://.../Company/Create`

I tried `RedirectToAction("Index");` It does not work also. And I do not think its a good MVC practice. I have a single layout and Company views are rendered with `RenderBody()`

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Edit :

This is my action method,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CompanyCreate model)
{
    /* Fill model with countries again */
    model.FillCountries();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /* Save it to database */
        unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.InsertCompany(model.Company);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        RedirectToAction("Index");
        return View();
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code for the action? return view won't change the url it shouldn't however I'm surprised the redirecttoaction isn't doing what you expect. I wouldn't call that bad practice either as it will help with double post.

Comment: thanks for comment.added the action code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redirect to another action if you want the url changed.

However [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) doesn't redirect instantly but returns a`RedirectToRouteResult` object which is an `ActionResult` object.

So you just need to return the result of `RedirectToAction` from  your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CompanyCreate model)
{
    /* Fill model with countries again */
    model.FillCountries();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /* Save it to database */
        unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.InsertCompany(model.Company);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I am coming from classic web forms. I thought it is something like Response.Redirect("url"). my bad :) thanks again.